# Nautilus open files in a running GVim instance as tab

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, gvim

Is it possible in (Unity) Ubuntu 12.04 to launch files in a running gVim instance as new tab from Nautilus? I can do that in a shell by 'gvim --remote-tab-silent' but i want this behavior also in Nautilus. Is it possible to pass the arguments?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i managed it myself with the alacart application. Here are the steps:

1. (install and) open alacarte
2. locate GVim (utilities)
3. change the command field in the settings to '**gvim -f --remote-tab-silent %F**'